# AngularJS: Controller split across two files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have controller code that I'm planning to use on multiple pages for multiple, single-page apps.

All the apps are very similar, but will need some of their own custom code.

I'd like to load the "master" controller file with each app, along with a separate "custom" file containing the much shorter custom code.

Is there any way that the "custom" file can add to the controller (and scope) defined in the "master" file?

Or override and redefine something defined in the "master" file without having to build a new controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular: Extending controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539999/angular-extending-controller) or [Angular: Split controller in multiple files] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819661/how-to-split-single-controller-in-multiple-js-files-in-angularjs)